# Where can I learn Mathematical Logic?

Tags: logic

Ive been getting into Wittgenstein and Russell lately and I wanted to know where I can study such maths and logic.

Comment: On any textbook... See e.g. Stephen Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) (2013).

Comment: More spcifically, on Russell, see [The Cambridge Companion to Bertrand Russell](https://books.google.it/books?id=obY48lTt-2AC&printsec=frontcover) and [The Palgrave Centenary Companion to Principia Mathematica](https://books.google.it/books?id=Vk-vAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: On Wittgenstein, [The Cambridge Companion to Wittgenstein](https://books.google.it/books?id=DtNoEoshjfkC&printsec=frontcover) and Michael Potter, [Wittgenstein's Notes on Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=IQk0cAAACAAJ).

Comment: i have a copy of lemmon's beginning logic, unread, but recommended to me. not really sure what "mathematical logic" is?

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN proof theory, recursion theory, set, model theory & such

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your motivations. You can study mathematical logic from a philosophical point of view, a computer science point of view, a purely mathematical point of view...
I don't know your background.

I think the best thing to do would be to check the "[Teach Yourself Logic Guide (2016)](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic2016.pdf)" of Peter Smith : coming from there http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/

Some (not too technical I think) introductions textbooks I can think of (but you can find plenty of them in the link above) :

**General Introduction**

- *Mathematical Logic*, Chiswell and Hodges. Very concise, easy to understand but not that complete.

**Gödel's Theorems**

- *An introduction to Gödels Theorems*, Smith

**Proof Theory**

It focuses on the study of proofs.

- *[An Introduction to Proof Theory](http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/handbookI/ChapterI.pdf)* (Comes from *The Handbook of Proof Theory)*, Buss

**A bit old but still interesting**

Interesting books from famous authors but use outdated notations and are more technical.

- *Introduction to logic and to the methodoly of deductive sciences*, Tarski
- *Mathematical Logic*, Kleene

Comment: Could you please specify why are Tarski and Kleene recommended only from a historic point of view ? More precisely, which technics there are not used anymore?

Comment: @AiliJ. It's not really that the concepts/technics used are totally outdated but rather that logic is described in a quite old way : not always clear and with old notations/presentations. I just think (maybe subjectively) that it doesn't fit for an introduction to Logic but rather for a technical investigation of the root of some ideas of logic. Moreover, it's not an exhaustive list, they're just two books that I happen to have.

Comment: Funnily enough I am reading Tarski just now and I found it very easy to understand without any previous studies of logic; and Kleene I bought 2 days ago online so it would be interesting to know into which chapters I shouldn't perhaps concentrate too much :)

Comment: @AiliJ. Oh ok. Maybe it was too subjective... and maybe it also depends on your background. I personally have a Computer Science background.

Comment: Kleene's book is still conceptually just fine, but it uses outdated notation and terminology.  Quine also wrote some basic logic texts but they have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a FREE and very well designed MOOC (Massively Open Online Course) by Professor [Keith Devlin](http://devlinsangle.blogspot.com/) of Stanford University:

https://www.coursera.org/learn/mathematical-thinking

It was designed as a transitional course from high school to university level math and is a great indtroduction to mathematical thinking. He's also got some [great lectures available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpGHT1n4-mAvzAtg6Qo8aTld6goSPxo4o).

It's not specifically "mathematical logic" as stated in the OP title. But for someone interested in "math and logic" as stated in the post, the course is a great intro to mathematical thinking including truth tables, existential quantifiers, infinity, set theory and such.

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Comment: hm well idk how much of it is logic based. cool link tho

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN It's not specifically "mathematical logic" as stated in the OP title but for someone interested in "math and logic" as stated in the post, the course is a great intro to mathematical thinking including truth tables, existential quantifiers, infinity, set theory and such

Comment: This seems valid as an answer to me. Why is this downvoted?

Comment: very useful link :)